# Tiny AES vs AES algorithm

Tags: aes

Is [Tiny AES](https://github.com/kokke/tiny-AES-c) algorithm any different from the standard AES algorithm? I have come across mentions of Tiny AES at a lot of places but none which define it's architecture.

Comment: from the readme, "This is a small and portable implementation of the AES ECB, CTR and CBC encryption algorithms written in C."

Comment: So, is it safe to assume that the algorithms are exactly the same?

Comment: @TarunMittal yes.

Comment: You'd probably hurt yourself not using a better wrapped authenticated encryption API.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

"Normal" AES implementations and tiny-AES perform the same task.

As stated in the [README](https://github.com/kokke/tiny-AES-c/blob/master/README.md):

> This is a small and portable implementation of the AES ECB, CTR and CBC encryption algorithms written in C.

It's simply an implementation with low memory usage. The reason for the existance of tiny-aes can be traced back to the initial search for a replacement for DES (which would then become AES). One of these requirements were that they should have low memory usage for implementations suitable for example in SmartCards.

As stated in their paper ([Second AES candidate conference, section 5](http://Smart%20Cards:%20Implementations%20and%20Related%20Attacks)) they performed tests on the different submitted AES candidates, one of which was memory usage.

Comment: One may want to note that this implementation makes no claims about (cache) timing side-chanell resistance if that is something one is worried about.